# Pass a query by Django to Javascript to work with it

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a view which responsible for showing all recieved messages.

```
@authenticated_user
def home(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(user = request.user) #This Used to show Profile of the User in Navbar
    try:
        allMessages = Messages.objects.filter(reciever = request.user)
        arabic_messages_ids = []
        for message in allMessages:
            if re.search(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]', message.message):
                arabic_messages_ids.append(message.id)

        unread_messages = Messages.objects.filter(reciever = request.user, is_read = False).values_list('id',flat=True)
    except Messages.DoesNotExist:
        allMessages = 0
        unread_messages = 0

    return render(request, "CSM/home.html", {'employee' : employee, 'messages' : allMessages, 'unreaded' : unread_messages, 'ar_messages_ids':arabic_messages_ids})
```

I have in my template a div in the left which responsible for showing User or The Senders of the Messages, and in the Right div show all the messages.

What I want is : My sender are in  tags. I want when I click on a sender the right div show only the correspondant message of that sender.

Message model has fields : sender(user), reciever(user), message(textfield), date_created(datetime), is_read(boolean)

I'm expecting a code by Javascript or some trick by html and css

Answer (score 0):

I get it with js:

```
        allMessages = document.querySelectorAll('.message-visible');
    allUser = document.querySelectorAll('.user');

    allUser.forEach(function (userElement) {
        userElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            allMessages.forEach(function (messageElement) {
                if(userElement.id == messageElement.id){
                    messageElement.classList.remove('hidden')
                }else{
                    messageElement.classList.add('hidden')
                }
            })

        })
    });
```

I add an id to the user and message tags : {{message.reciever}}{{message.id}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).